# mvc4 how to get specific data of html helper while has multiple models in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The code is:

Model

Use entity frame work to show 2 tables in database and put these into a model

```
public class UserDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserItems> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductItems> Products { get; set; }
}

[Table("db_user")]
public class UserItems
{
    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="E-mail")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}

[Table("Products")]
public class ProductItems
{
    [Display(Name="Product Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Product Number")]
    public int number { get; set; }
}

public class DbCombine
{
    public IEnumerable< UserItems> UserItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable< ProductItems> ProductItems { get; set; }
}
```

Controller
Pass the model with tables' list to the view.

```
public ActionResult testingView()
    {
        var model = new DbCombine
        {
            ProductItems = db.Products.ToList(),
            UserItems = db.Users.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
@model MVCselfcode.Models.DbCombine

<div>@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.UserItems*.name*)</div>
```

The problem is I can't get the the detail data in strong type, like the code in view, it can't have `.name` after`m=>m.UserItems`.

The error message is " This model doesn't include the 'name' defination".

How can I use strong type for this? or should I change the method to combine tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserItems` is of type `IEnumerable<UserItems>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a property called `name`.  Each *instance* of the object has that property, but a *collection* of the objects does not.

Which element in the collection are you trying to edit?

In order to get the HTML helper to identify the property you want, you need to supply it with an instance of that property:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.UserItems.First().name)
```

This may intuitively seem like it would throw an exception if the collection is empty, but it actually doesn't *invoke* the call to `First()`.  This simply allows the framework to reflect into the definition of the type returned by `First()` so it can build the resulting HTML.

If you're actually looking to edit the records, you'll probably want to create a custom editor for your `UserItems` type and iterate over the `UserItems` property to display an editor for each one.  Additionally, to avoid confusion, I suggest not naming the *plural* property and the *singular* class with the exact same name.  Perhaps the class should be called `UserItem` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the details and what I actually want to do is use that text box in create a new name, but this help me some. thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have doesn't make sense. `UserItems` is a *collection* which means it includes multiple `UserItems` entities. The question is which item in the `Model.UserItems` collection do you want to reference.

For example, did you perhaps mean to enumerate over the collection and produce a div for each item:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.UserItems)
{
    <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => item.name)</div>
}
```